# Invalid Post - Return to Same Form

Tags: django

First, I'm not using django forms which I know could handle this.  I may rewrite the app to do that but I'm looking for a quicker solution for the short term.

Problem:
Users submit a form with invalid data.  I'd like to point them back to the same page with an error message and populate repopulate all the data they've already provided.

It seems like you should be able to do this with render_to_response() but I'm not quite sure how.  Do I just edit the request and pass it back into the render_to_response?  Any concrete examples or links to examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In my (rather strong) opinion, django forms would be a super simple solution, as all the validations, etc are already done for you.  But for your solution, just send the error fields in the context of either `render` or `render_to_response`

Comment: Since this is *exactly* what Django forms do, I can't imagine why you'd look for another solution.